# Getting "Cannot GET /isFavorite" on my Node.js app hosted on DigitalOcean

Tags: mysql, node.js, post, digital-ocean, body-parser

Why am I getting the following error?  I have a small Nodejs app hosted on DigitalOcean. I am getting the following error "Cannot GET /isFavorite" when I run the following post command in Postman: "http://octopus-app-s7q5v.ondigitalocean.app:8080/isFavorite" with body JSON parameters of:

```
{
    "userid": "101",
    "petid": "1"
}
```

The route I have for the app is an `app.post("/isFavorite")` and not an `app.get`.  It is connected to a MySQL database which is also hosted on DigitalOcean.  I have included a small version of the code for the app below.  Why would I be getting this error? When I add an app.get("/") and return a response of "Hello" that works.  It runs locally.  I have configured all the environment variables in DigitalOcean settings. I have the "ca-certificate.crt" in the root of my Nodejs app.  DigitalOcean app platform says it builds and deploys fine on the server.

Also, regarding the console.logs I have added to the code, where are they stored?  I can see the one which starts the webserver and listens but not any of the others. The app is listening on port 8080 and has an IP address of 0.0.0.0.

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const querystring = require('querystring');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
app.use("/", router);

const mysql = require('mysql');
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/isFavorite", (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.debug("isFavorite Start");

        const conn = mysql.createConnection({
            host: process.env.DBHOST,
            port: process.env.DBPORT,
            user: process.env.DBUSER,
            database: process.env.DBNAME,
            password: process.env.DBPASSWORD
        });

        console.log("isFavorite logged on to db");

        let selectQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM Favorites WHERE userID = ? AND petID = ?';
        let query = mysql.format(selectQuery,[req.body.userid, req.body.petid]);
        conn.query(query,(err, response, fields) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send("Error querying database.");
                return;
            }
            // rows added
            console.log("isFavorite");
            console.log(response.length);
            if (response.length > 0) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                res.status(200).json({IsFavorite: response[0].c >= 1});
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({IsFavorite: false});
            }
    });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let IP = process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1';
app.listen(PORT, IP, () => {
    console.log('Server is running at port ' + PORT + ' and IP = ' + IP);
});
```

Comment: If you see an error `Cannot GET /isFavorite` it means your app is receiving `GET` request not a `POST` so you must have selected `GET` in Postman.

Comment: Make sure you selected the post method in the postman and make sure you deployed the latest version of your app

Comment: You should declare the route as a `get`: `app.get("/isFavorite", (req, res) => { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, Ipizzindev, but I don't think I can because I need to pass in the body and I may be wrong but in my research, I found that get does not allow parameters in the body.

Comment: I did choose post as the HTTP verb.  But it still said it was trying to do a get in postman.  I did find that the server was doing a redirect but not sure if that was causing something to go wrong

Comment: Also I found that someone was having a similar problem and it was the negex that was causing the problem but I am using App Platform and I dont think it uses negex.  Atleast I was not able to find the logs that were mentioned or the negex program on the hosting server.

Comment: Why are you using two JSON middlewares? Just use the ones from Express, you can remove `body-parser` entirely